# Identity Server 4 Use a new Signing Key after Startup

Tags: identityserver4, signing

I have IdentityServer4 setup in an aspnetcore API Service (running in Service Fabric as a Stateless Service) which uses a signing certificate generated and held in Azure Key Vault. In the Startup class I'm using the `AddSigningCredential` method to set the initial signing certificate, but I'm unsure of the steps needed to use a new signing certificate when the initial one expires.

I have Key Vault configured to generate a new certificate before the previous one expires and have a background process running in my service to periodically retrieve the certificate from Key Vault and check if it is different from the one currently used by IdentityServer.

What I don't know how to do is to set the new certificate for use by IdentityServer. As far as I can tell, I can't use the `AddSigningCredential` method again as the DI Container doesn't allow new dependencies to be registered after startup. Also the `DefaultSigningCredentialsStore` that is registered for the `ISigningCredentialStore` dependency doesn't allow updates to the `SigningCredentials` after construction.

Do I have to write my own version of the `ISigningCredentialStore` and `IValidationKeysStore` to allow updates to the `SigningCredentials` to be made? It seems like this would be a common usage and should be in the product itself, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if IdentityServer looks at its expiration. Because it shouldn't matter as it is just used for encryption of the tokens. Otherwise you should prevent the certificate to expire.

The certificate is used to encrypt and decrypt the tokens. This prevents others to tamper with the token.

If you change the certificate then all existing tokens become invalid at once, because the server cannot decode the incoming tokens anymore. That is the same behaviour when you use TemporarySigningCredentials and restart IdentityServer.

So it shouldn't change at all. I think it would be best to create a specific certificate (that optionally never expires) just for IdentityServer.

Comment: You are right that IdentityServer would still sign tokens with an expired certificate. It does log a warning when doing so however. I work in an environment where the security team wouldn't be happy with those warnings or with having a never expiring certificate, so I have to code for the eventuality that the certificate will need rolling at some point. By implementing an IValidationKeysStore I can put the expiring certificate key in it and still validate tokens issued before the new key was added.